# Best way to setup a i8n in a database

Tags: database, database-design

i face the problem to develop a database with a **support of multi languages**. 
My first approch was it, to write for each language a extra table. 
For example I handle recipes, so I created various templates according to the language:

```
- enRecipe
- deRecipe
- frRecipe
```

Is this correct or is their a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with the design will be shown when other languages needs to be added to the design, when you will need to add more tables.
Also it would be hard to find witch language have not implemented specific recipe keys.
 
I will suggest having a design like bellow:
[image]

About the comment:
To generalize the solution for other entities like Ingredients, there may be alternatives:

1. Having a Resource table that contains sting resource keys, it will
   be very likely to have resource files in your application (files are
   replaced with tables). 
    Note that in this design text keys are
   separated from business entities like Recipe and Ingredient.
   [image]
2. A more specific design will be having a base table for every
   business entity that may need multi-language support, this base
   table will have the the name key that must be translated.
   [image]

Comment: This sounds pretty clear. But if I have more than one table, aside Recipe. Maybe Ingredients, the relationship tables will double and so on....